# howto filter this with regex?

Tags: regex, filter

I have the problem I want to extract these numbers from a string, BUT only when they're not followed by "foo".

Example:

- "12:13 Foo" (no)
- "12:22 Bla" (yes)

I have the Regex:

```
(\d+):(\d+)
```

and don't know what to do to prevent it from selecting strings with the "Foo" after the digits.

Answer (score 4):

This depends somewhat on your regex flavour, but if it supports [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) you can use:

```
(\d+):(\d+)(?:\s+(?!Foo)|$)
```

This doesn't, however, match `12:34Bar` (no space between the 4 and B).

Another edit: If you can use atomic groping, then I think this will cover the cases where there's no space between the last digit and the word following it as well as the previous cases ([rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/7kd9xfwHEi)):

```
(\d+):(?>\d+)(?!\s*F[oO][oO]) 

#Or just (\d+):(?>\d+)(?!\s*Foo) if case-insensitive
```

Comment: @mullek, note that this only works if your `\d+:\d+` is at the start of the input string. If you're searching a string for these occurrences, remove the `^` and `$` from the suggested regex.

Comment: @eldarerathis, that won't match `12:22 Bla` since the regex only matches strings ending with `\s*$`

Comment: @mullek: Yes, @Bart Kiers makes an excellent point. If this pattern exists in the middle of a string then remove the anchors (`^` and `$`).

Comment: Nope, `(\d+):(\d+)\s+[^Ff][^Oo][^Oo]` will not match `11:11 AB` to name just one string. I'd just roll back and only leave `(\d+):(\d+)\s*(?!Foo)` in place.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Hm, that's true. I'll just roll with what we know works.

Comment: (\d+):(\d+)\s*(?!Foo) dont work, but (\d+):(\d+)\s(?!Foo) do but dont mathes with 1:1)

Comment: @NullUserException: I just realized - I meant to use `\s+`, otherwise the `*` gives back its space and does match `12:34 Foo` (unless it's made posessive). I've amended that. That creates another complexity, though.

Comment: @eldarerathis, no, changing `\s*` into `\s+` will only make  it fail to match the string `12:34` (without a space after it). Like I said: include the `\s*`, or `\s+` inside the look-ahead and you're done.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: `(\s+(?!Foo)|$)` fixes the `12:34` with no space after it issue. I tried `(\d+):(\d+)(?!\s*Foo)` again in Python and it matched `12:34 Foo`. Edit: Actually, the issue is that it matches `12:3` with the `(\d+):(\d+)` and then the last digit matches the `(?!\s*Foo)`, disregarding the fact that ` Foo` comes one character later.

Comment: I know it fixes it, I just find it too complicated. See my answer, which I think is much easier to read, and does practically the same.

Answer (score 2):

**(updated answer)**

```
(\d+):(\d+)(?:\s(?!\s*Foo)|$)
```

By adding a negative lookahead `(?!Foo)`, it will only match strings which don't end with "Foo".  It will also capture the two digit groups into backreferences 1 and 2.

Matches:

- 12:34
- 12:22 Bla
- 1:1

Won't match:

- 12:13 Foo
- 12:13Foo
- 12:13   Foo

Comment: But it will not match `11:11  Foo` (two spaces between `11` and `Foo`) or `22:22` (without a space)

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have added that disclaimer :p This regex assumes there is exactly one space in between (per the examples provided).  If the number of spaces is unknown or varies, changing `\s`  to `\s*` will allow that.

Comment: Note that I voted your answer down before I answered myself (else I hadn't done so). I did so because @mullek specifically mentioned an earlier answer of @eldarerathis being incorrect because it did not match `1:1`: something your answer also does not match (and is therefor incorrect).

Answer (score -2):

```
(\d+):(\d+) (\s*)(^[Ff]^[Oo]^[Oo])(\s*)
```

Comment: The `^` now matches the start of the input, it does not negate, as you probably think it does. It only negates when placed at the start of a character class: `[^a]` matches any character except an `a`.